# What is the meaning of "holds no small amount of contempt"?

Tags: meaning

[**SOURCE**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051459/synopsis)

> Brick's wife Maggie is clever and outspoken, and
>   **holds no small amount of contempt** for Gooper and Mae's entitled
>   attitudes and five spoiled and obnoxious offspring who run around the
>   house unsupervised.

Is author indirectly saying that Maggie always like Gooper and Mae's attitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of the word "no" as a determinant to mean "not a" is not particularly common in modern English, except in fixed expressions, eg "This is no joke" means "this is not a joke"

"Holding contempt for something" means believing it is inferior. The more contempt you have, the less you value something.

So Maggie does not hold a small amount of contempt for Gooper and Mae. Instead (we understand) Maggie holds a large amount of contempt for them. In other words. Maggie thinks Gooper and Mae are worthless. She does not like their attitudes.

Comment: please remove the word **Instead** in your answer.

Comment: @user60094: Why? It's entirely appropriate here.